# Where does WCF log the stuff if wmi is enabled?

Tags: wcf, logging, wmi, service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
```

I recently stumled across this setting in WCF, where you can enabled WMI logging. Where does it log to? and what is logged? There is no mention of that..
Pleaselet me know...

Answer (score 3):

It is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx) and example [here](http://nayyeri.net/blog/use-wmi-provider-in-windows-communication-foundation/).